# Why is my neural network unable to solve MNIST? (debug help)

Tags: java, neural-network

I have implemented a general neural network framework from scratch, and ensured it is ostensibly doing the right thing by solving the XOR problem (I have done so with both 1 and more hidden layers to ensure I don't have a bug in my multi-hidden layer implementation).

I've also implemented my own Matrix math library from scratch (more as an exercise in matrix math as a precursor to understanding the NN math rather than for lightweight reasons).

So now I am trying to finalise the successful functionality of the framework by trying to solve MNIST with a vector-input network with layers of size {784, 100, 50, 10}, a learning rate of 0.2, and weight initialisation of random float in range {-1, 1} and zero-initialisation of biases.

After training the network on all 60,000 training examples (running backprop for each one, no mini-batching), I'm getting rubbish out. I've verified that I'm not putting rubbish in, however I've written the framework in Java and the training data needs quite a bit of prep for it to be usable.

I have mapped each value {0, 255} between {0.01, 1} using transformation x -> x * (0.99 / 255) + 0.01 to prevent zero-adjustment of biases.

That's the background, I'll dump the code below, hopefully it isn't too terribly written:

## Network class

```
public class Network {
    int inputNum, outputNum;
    Layer[] layers;
    float cost;
    float learning_rate;
    
    public Network(int input, int[] hidden, int output, float learning_rate, float weight_bound) {
        this.inputNum = input;
        this.outputNum = output;
        this.layers = new Layer[hidden.length + 1];
        
        this.learning_rate = learning_rate;

        this.layers[0] = new Layer(input, hidden[0], weight_bound);
        this.layers[this.layers.length - 1] = new Layer(hidden[hidden.length - 1], output, weight_bound);

        for (int i = 1; i < hidden.length; i++) {
            layers[i] = new Layer(hidden[i - 1], hidden[i], weight_bound);
        }
    }

    public Matrix predict(Matrix input) throws DimensionException {
        Matrix currentIn = input;
        for (Layer l : this.layers) {
            currentIn = l.forwardPropogate(currentIn);
        }

        return currentIn;
    }

    public void train(Matrix[] inputs, Matrix[] labels) throws DimensionException {
        for (int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            Matrix currentIn = inputs[i];
            for (Layer l : this.layers) {
                currentIn = l.forwardPropogate(currentIn);
            }

            Matrix error = Matrix.sub(labels[i], currentIn);
            this.cost = Matrix.apply(error, x -> 0.5f * x * x).sum();
            for (int l = this.layers.length - 1; l >= 0; l--) {
                error = this.layers[l].backwardPropogate(error, learning_rate);
            }
        }
    }

    public static float sigmoid(float x) {
        return 1 / (1 + (float) Math.exp(-x));
    }

    public static float dsigmoid(float y) {
        return y * (1 - y);
    }
}
```

## Layer class

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Layer {
    Matrix weights;
    Matrix biases;

    Matrix inValues;
    Matrix outValues;

    public Layer(int input_size, int output_size, float init_bound) {
        this.weights = new Matrix(output_size, input_size);
        this.weights.apply(x -> (float) ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(-init_bound, init_bound));
        this.biases = new Matrix(output_size, 1);

    }

    public Matrix forwardPropogate(Matrix in) throws DimensionException {
        this.inValues = in;
        this.outValues = this.weights.multiply(this.inValues);
        this.outValues.add(this.biases);
        this.outValues.apply(x -> Network.sigmoid(x));

        return outValues;
    } 

    public Matrix backwardPropogate(Matrix out_error, float learning_rate) throws DimensionException {
        Matrix errorByDSig = Matrix.apply(this.outValues, x -> Network.dsigmoid(x)).multiply(out_error);

        Matrix weightAdjustment = errorByDSig.multiply(Matrix.transpose(this.inValues));
        weightAdjustment.multiply(learning_rate);

        Matrix biasAdjustment = errorByDSig.copy();
        biasAdjustment.multiply(learning_rate);

        Matrix newError = Matrix.transpose(this.weights).multiply(errorByDSig);

        this.weights.add(weightAdjustment);
        this.biases.add(biasAdjustment);

        return newError;
    }
}
```

## Matrix library

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.function.Function;

class Matrix {
    int rows, cols;
    float[][] matrix;

    public Matrix (int rows, int cols) {
        this.rows = rows;
        this.cols = cols;
        this.matrix = new float[this.rows][this.cols];
    }

    public void multiply(float n) {
        this.apply(x -> (float)x * n);
    }

    public Matrix multiply(Matrix m) throws DimensionException {
        Matrix newM;

        if (this.cols == m.cols && this.rows == m.rows) {
            newM = this.copy();
            for (int r = 0; r < m.rows; r++) {
                for (int c = 0; c < m.cols; c++) {
                    newM.matrix[r][c] *= m.matrix[r][c];
                }
            }
            return newM;
        }

        if (this.cols == m.rows) {

            newM = new Matrix(this.rows, m.cols);

            for (int r = 0; r < this.rows; r++) {
                for (int c = 0; c < m.cols; c++) {
                    float sum = 0;
                    for (int s = 0; s < m.rows; s++) {
                        sum += this.matrix[r][s] * m.matrix[s][c];
                    }
                    newM.matrix[r][c] = sum;
                }
            }

            return newM;
        }

        throw new DimensionException("Matrix dimensions are incorrect");

    }

    public void add(float n) {
        this.apply(x -> x + n);
    }

    public void add(Matrix m) throws DimensionException{
        if (this.cols != m.cols || this.rows != m.rows) {
            throw new DimensionException("Matrix dimensions are incorrect");
        }

        for (int r = 0; r < this.rows; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < this.cols; c++) {
                this.matrix[r][c] += m.matrix[r][c];
            }
        }
    }

    public void sub(float n) {
        this.add(-n);
    }

    public void sub(Matrix m) throws DimensionException {
        this.add(Matrix.apply(m, x -> -x));
    }

    public void apply(Function<Float, Float> f) {
        for (int r = 0; r < this.rows; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < this.cols; c++) {
                this.matrix[r][c] = f.apply(this.matrix[r][c]);
            }
        }
    }

    public Matrix copy() {
        Matrix m = new Matrix(this.rows, this.cols);
        for (int r = 0; r < this.rows; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < this.cols; c++) {
                m.matrix[r][c] = this.matrix[r][c];
            }
        }

        return m;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String s = "";
        for (int r = 0; r < this.rows; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < this.cols; c++) {
                s += Float.toString(this.matrix[r][c]) + " ";
            }
            s += "\n";
        }

        return s;
    }

    public float sum() {
        float total = 0;

        for (int r = 0; r < this.rows; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < this.cols; c++) {
                total += this.matrix[r][c];
            }
        }

        return total;
    }

    public static Matrix multiply(Matrix m, float n) {
        Matrix newM = m.copy();
        newM.add(n);

        return newM;
    }

    public static Matrix multiply(Matrix m, Matrix n) throws DimensionException {
        Matrix newM = m.copy();
        return newM.multiply(n);
    }

    public static Matrix add(Matrix m, float n) {
        Matrix newM = m.copy();
        newM.apply(x -> x + n);

        return newM;
    }

    public static Matrix add(Matrix m, Matrix n) throws DimensionException {
        Matrix newM = m.copy();
        newM.add(n);

        return newM;
    }

    public static Matrix sub(Matrix m, float n) {
        Matrix newM = m.copy();
        newM.sub(n);

        return newM;
    }

    public static Matrix sub(Matrix m, Matrix n) throws DimensionException {
        Matrix newM = m.copy();
        newM.sub(n);

        return newM;
    }

    public static Matrix apply(Matrix m, Function<Float, Float> f) {
        Matrix newM = m.copy();
        newM.apply(f);

        return newM;
    }

    public static Matrix random(int rows, int cols, int bound) {
        Matrix m = new Matrix(rows, cols);

        m.apply(x -> x + ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(bound));

        return m;
    }

    public static Matrix fromArray(int rows, int cols, float[] array) {
        Matrix newMatrix = new Matrix(rows, cols);

        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
                newMatrix.matrix[r][c] = array[r * cols + c];        
            }
        }

        return newMatrix;
    }

    public static Matrix transpose(Matrix m) {
        Matrix newMatrix = new Matrix(m.cols, m.rows);
        
        for (int r = 0; r < m.rows; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < m.cols; c++) {
                newMatrix.matrix[c][r] = m.matrix[r][c];
            }
        }

        return newMatrix;

    }
}
```

## Training / getting an output

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class tests {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws DimensionException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        File training_files = new File("C:/Users/2001b/OneDrive/Desktop/data/data/training");
        File label_file = new File("C:/Users/2001b/OneDrive/Desktop/data/data/labels.csv");

        Matrix[] training_data = new Matrix[60000];
        Matrix[] training_labels = new Matrix[60000];

        int file_count = 0;
        
        for (File f : training_files.listFiles()) {
            float[] pixels = new float[784];
            int p_count = 0;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                double[] values = Arrays.stream(line.split(",")).mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).toArray();
                for (double v : values) {
                    pixels[p_count++] = ((float) v * (0.99f / 255) + 0.01f);
                }
            }
            training_data[file_count++] = Matrix.fromArray(784, 1, pixels);
            br.close();
        }
        
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(label_file));
        String line;
        int count = 0;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            int value = Integer.valueOf(line);
            Matrix answerMatrix = new Matrix(10, 1);
            answerMatrix.matrix[value][0] = 1;
            training_labels[count++] = answerMatrix;
        }
        br.close();

        System.out.println(training_labels[5]);

        Network network = new Network(784, new int[] {100, 50}, 10, 0.2f, 1);

        network.train(training_data, training_labels);
        System.out.println(network.predict(training_data[5]));
    }
}
```

After training with 10-vector all-zero labels (other than the expected 1), I'm getting output vectors like this:

```
0.0629406 
0.09087993
0.09197301
0.08965302
0.052927334
0.08770021
0.11267567
0.071576655
0.12798244
0.09146147
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: What kind of output would you prefer? Note that MNIST contains multiple classes you you _might_ want to have multiple output nodes (together with e.g. softmax or cross entropy for the loss).

Comment: I have 10 output nodes, and I want the index of the highest activated node to be the answer

Comment: Does this not fit your actual results? What's your accuracy? Does the accuracy change while training? Is there overfitting?

Comment: Does no better than random guessing while training on all 60,000

Comment: How does the error/loss change while training?

Comment: Not at all. Cost stays at either 4 or 5 each time it's run

Comment: Are you reading the training input files and training labels in the same order?

Comment: Yep, checked all that